# Error occuring in authenticating my weburl to windows

Tags: windows

I have doing push notifications for my windows phone 8.1.
for getting push notifications i am trying to authenticate with WNS(windows notification service) in order to get a access token..

Here is my code..

```
protected async void  GetAccessToken(string secret, string sid)
    {
    var urlSe =WebUtility.UrlEncode(secret);
    var urlsId = WebUtility.UrlEncode(sid);
    var body = String.Format("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&scope=notify.windows.com",urlSe ,urlsId);
    Uri url1 = new Uri("https://login.live.com/accesstoken.srf" + body);
    String response1;
    System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpclient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    using (var client = httpclient)
    {
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage respnse = await client.GetAsync(url1);
     var result =await respnse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();        
    }
}
```

Whenever it try's to enter the "respnse" line of code it gives me a exception

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Net.Http.Phone.ni.DLL

I don't know what is the problem,i referred to the following link

and created this code..

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868206.aspx

Note:the code is for windows 8 phone,but i am doing for windows 8.1 phone app